# Text of JLabel moves out of JPanel

Tags: swing, jpanel, jlabel

I have a JPanel with specific size. I have added a JLabel on it. Now the text of JLabel is dynamic and comes from the database. When I add this data to JLabel, instead of it staying in the JPanel, it spreads out.

When it happens, the data inside the JPanel is visible but the one outside the JPanel is not visible (which is obvious). I want to know if there is a way by which the data instead of going out of JPanel, will stay in JPanel itself (means it automatically adds a newline and moves to newline instead of going out).

Comment: Did you have a question?  BTW - spelling 'thanks' as 'thanx' makes you seem a buffoon.

Comment: *"I use this website to learn new concepts,.."*  Do you know how many people opened your question, saw immature text-speak, & immediately closed it without offering an answer?  I don't either, beyond saying it is something between 0 & **78** (# of views - # of answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JLabel doesn't have a method for that. But you have a few options:

1. Use **HTML tags** in text you set `"Hello<br/>World"`.
2. Use JTextArea or JEditorPane and disable editing. **JTextArea** have the `setLineWrap(true)` method, and **JEditorPane** wraps lines by default.

Comment: Thanx MByD. Using HTML tags was useful.

Comment: i used setLineWrap(true); method but the line break after random letter.. I want break to be only after word completion...

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something more robust than a simple `JLabel`, like a `JTextArea`. Your best place to learn how to achieve the desired effect would be to read the Swing tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html). Since you know the size of your `JPanel` you can set the size of your `JTextArea` and it should automatically line-wrap to accommodate for your variable-sized strings.